# id column as a sequence

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using an interactive grid, the table I'm using is as follows :

```
ID, ACCOUNT_MANAGER, TARGET, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DT
```

in the interactive grid, i'm only showing these columns :

```
ACCOUNT_MANAGER, TARGET
```

the user will be able to insert or update the previous two columns only ,
the id value will be taken from a sequence, as for created_by and CREATED_DT the value will be retrieved as follows:

```
declare 
seq number;
begin
    select sequence1.nextval into seq from dual;

    case :APEX$ROW_STATUS
    when 'C' then 
         insert into tbl(ID, ACCOUNT_MANAGER, TARGET,CREATED_DT,CREATED_BY )
         values (seq, :ACCOUNT_MANAGER,:TARGET, :SYSDATE, :APP_USER )
         returning rowid into :ROW_ID;
    when 'U' then
        update tbl
           set ACCOUNT_MANAGER= :ACCOUNT_MANAGER,
               TARGET = :TARGET
               CREATED_DT= SYSDATE,
               CREATED_BY = :APP_USER
         where rowid  = :ROW_ID;
    
    end case;
end;
```

i get this error, please help

```
ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "ROW_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using rowid without underscore like below?

```
declare 
seq number;
begin
    select sequence1.nextval into seq from dual;
    case :APEX$ROW_STATUS
    when 'C' then 
         insert into tbl(ID, ACCOUNT_MANAGER, TARGET,CREATED_DT,CREATED_BY )
         values (seq, :ACCOUNT_MANAGER,:TARGET, :SYSDATE, :APP_USER )
         returning rowid into :ROWID;
    when 'U' then
        update tbl
           set ACCOUNT_MANAGER= :ACCOUNT_MANAGER,
               TARGET = :TARGET
               CREATED_DT= SYSDATE,
               CREATED_BY = :APP_USER
         where rowid  = :ROWID;
    
    end case;
end;
```

Comment: I did something else, and it worked for me, i did'nt use the rowid, instead i returned the id created in the table